# How to call a parameterised constructor present in a base class?

Tags: java, constructor

Iam beginner in programming iam struct at how to call parameterised constructor presented in base class.
My code:

```
    public class base {
    int a, b;

    base(int x) {
        a = x;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

 static class derived extends base {
        derived(int y) {
            b = y;
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        derived de = new derived(10);

    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the tag `multiple-inheritance` from your question because it's not the case

Answer (score 4):

`super(int)` refers to `base(int x)`:

```
derived(int y) {
    super(DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_A);
    b = y;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

where `DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_A` is an `int` value to initialise the field `a` from `base`.

Please, follow the Java naming convention, your code is hard to read. The first letter of the class name should be capitalized.

Comment: You might also want to show the better *(my opinion)* constructor: `derived(int x, int y)`

Answer (score 1):

When ever you creates object of any class constructor of parent is also called 
In your case   **derived de = new derived(10);** Will call base() in derived(int y) ..

Either add default constructor in base class or call parametarized constructor form base

```
public class Base {
int a, b;
Base(){} // if you remove this please add super(0) in Derived(int y)
Base(int x) {
    a = x;
    System.out.println(a);
}
static class Derived extends Base {
    Derived(int y) {
 // super(0);  // uncomment this if you dont want to add default constructor in your parent class
   b = y;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Derived de = new Derived(10);

}
```

}